# Linked list mutation

Tags: python

for a function that does this:

> Remove all the nodes containing the value in link. Assume that the
>       the first element is never removed.

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't remove the second item. I'd appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm not doing right here.

for example:

```
>>> l1 = Link(0, Link(2, Link(2, Link(3, Link(1, Link(2, Link(3)))))))
>>> print(l1)
<0 2 2 3 1 2 3>
>>> remove_all(l1, 2)
>>> print(l1)
```

the correct answer should be `<0 3 1 3>`  but I get `<0 2 3 1 3>`

the code:

```
def remove_all(link , value):
     assert link is not Link.empty
     if link.first == value and link.rest == Link.empty:
         link.first = Link()  
     elif link.first == value:
         link.first, link.rest = link.rest.first,link.rest.rest   
     remove_all(link.rest, value)
class Link:
    """A linked list.

    >>> s = Link(1)
    >>> s.first
    1
    >>> s.rest is Link.empty
    True
    >>> s = Link(2, Link(3, Link(4)))
    >>> s.first = 5
    >>> s.rest.first = 6
    >>> s.rest.rest = Link.empty
    >>> s                                    # Displays the contents of repr(s)
    Link(5, Link(6))
    >>> s.rest = Link(7, Link(Link(8, Link(9))))
    >>> s
    Link(5, Link(7, Link(Link(8, Link(9)))))
    >>> print(s)                             # Prints str(s)
    <5 7 <8 9>>
    """
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest is not Link.empty:
            rest_repr = ', ' + repr(self.rest)
        else:
            rest_repr = ''
        return 'Link(' + repr(self.first) + rest_repr + ')'

    def __str__(self):
        string = '<'
        while self.rest is not Link.empty:
            string += str(self.first) + ' '
            self = self.rest
        return string + str(self.first) + '>'
```

Comment: It would really help if you gave a [mre]. To start, `link` and `Link` are not defined, though I can infer what they are. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. If you want more advice, check out [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You function doesn't need to be recursive. Also, you need to remain on the same object when you remove the next one because the new "rest" may also have a value to remove (i.e. consecutive values that need to be removed)

```
def remove(link,value):
    while link is not Link.empty:
        if link.rest is not Link.empty and link.rest.first == value:
            link.rest = link.rest.rest
        else:
            link = link.rest
```